# Always execute parent function in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to define a parent view in Backbone which extends Backbone.View. All child views will inherit from the parent view. But everytime I make a new instance of a child view, I want a function in the parent view to execute. Here's an example (the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzowyhc5/4/)):

```
    SimpleSample = {};

    SimpleSample.ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            //always execute this
            console.log('in parent view initialise');
        }
    });

    SimpleSample.Child1 = SimpleSample.ParentView.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('in child 1 initialise');
        }
    });


    SimpleSample.Child2 = SimpleSample.ParentView.extend({

    });

    SimpleSample.App = function(){
        this.start = function(){
            var child1 = new SimpleSample.Child1();
            var child2 = new SimpleSample.Child2();
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        var app = new SimpleSample.App();
        app.start();
    })
```

The output of this is, as you would expect:

```
in child 1 initialise
in parent view initialise
```

Because I have defined initialize() for Child1, the code in initialize() defined in ParentView does not run. I do not want to have to explicitly call a ParentView function from each child. Is it possible to always execute some code in ParentView every time there is a new instance of a view which inherits from ParentView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the constructor (in the parent view)

```
SimpleSample.ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function(options){
       //always execute this
       console.log('in parent view initialise');
   }

   constructor: function (options) {
       Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
       SimpleSample.ParentView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, options);
   }

});
```

That takes care of calling the original constructor function from Backbone.View and also calls your initialize function.

Now your child views should be free to define their own initialize functions.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using the [Backbone-Super](https://github.com/lukasolson/backbone-super) plugin for over a year.  Well-tested & easy to add to most projects.  With it the sub-class's initialize would look something like this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    console.log('in child 1 initialise');
    this._super(options);
}
```

It never calls the super-class "automatically", but it does make it easy enough to make the call correctly.  It works with all methods too, not just `initialize`, so ...

```
set: function(attributes, options) {
     this._super(attributes, options);
     console.log('Child 1 just had "set" called');
}
```

Comment: I think the point was that the OP didn't want to add the "super" call in every subclass seeing as the question specifically mentions *I do not want to have to explicitly call a ParentView function from each child*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real super in javascript.

You could call a function in the parent view explicit via the prototype object

```
SimpleSample.Child1 = SimpleSample.ParentView.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('in child 1 initialise');
        SimpleSample.ParentView.prototype.initialize.apply(this);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzowyhc5/5/

Comment: so its necessary to include this in every child view?

Comment: sorry I didn't read your question correctly. I thought your question was how to call a function from the parent view. I don't know if it's possible to automatically call the parent function without calling it explicit in the child view.